# Flutter Share package causing not helpful error

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use the Share package provided by the Flutter team. I tried implementing the package and when that didn't work I tried straight up copying and pasting their code, but got an error just the same. Unfortunately the error is not very helpful and the description of the error says "we need to explain this better". Any ideas?

[Here's the package I'm using](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share#-example-tab-)

My Code:

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text(
        'Share',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 93, 62, 1.0)),
    ),
    color: Colors.grey[100],
    onPressed: () {
        final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
        Share.share('Hello this is a test',
            sharePositionOrigin:
                box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) &
                box.size);
    },
),
```

The Error:

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: type 'RenderSliverList' is not a subtype of type 'RenderBox'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      _EverythingState._buildEventCards.<anonymous closure> (package:loopt_in/widgets/everything.dart:175:43)
flutter: #1      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
flutter: #2      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
flutter: #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
flutter: #4      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
flutter: #5      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
flutter: #6      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
flutter: #7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:184:20)
flutter: #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
flutter: #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
flutter: #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
flutter: #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
flutter: #12     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:165:13)
flutter: #13     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:119:5)
flutter: Handler: onTap
flutter: Recognizer:
flutter:   TapGestureRecognizer#ecc56(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, won arena, finalPosition:
flutter:   Offset(196.0, 747.5), sent tap down)
```

**Update**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

class Everything extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _EverythingState();
  }
}

class _EverythingState extends State<Everything> {
  Widget _buildEventCards(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 14.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              document['image'],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // Icon(document['icon']),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Wrap(
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Chip(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        label: Text(
                          document['date'],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        label: Text(document['source']),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        label: Text(
                          document['location'],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: width,
                    child: Text(
                      document['title'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Text(document['desc']),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'More',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 190, 208, 1.0)),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('webview clicked');
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WebviewScaffold(
                                    url: document['url'],
                                    appBar: AppBar(
                                      title: Text(document['source']),
                                      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(
                                        135,
                                        142,
                                        136,
                                        1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15.0,
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Share',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 93, 62, 1.0)),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        onPressed: () {
                          final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
                          Share.share('Hello this is a test',
                                  sharePositionOrigin:
                                      box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) &
                                          box.size);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stories').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _buildEventCards(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
          );
        });
  }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   // TODO: implement initState
  //   super.initState();

  //   FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
  //   var bannerAd = _buildBanner()..load();
  // }
}
```

**New Error Traceback**

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:291:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Share.share (package:share/share.dart:44:20)
#2      ShareButton.build.<anonymous closure> (package:loopt_in/widgets/everything.dart:220:17)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
```

Comment: This peace of code is working fine in both android and iOS I think the problem coming from somewhere else inside your code

Comment: @SaedNabil I will add the rest of my code to show

Comment: I fixed the issue please check the Edit section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue in this line

```
RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
```

the right side return RenderSliverList and you assigning it to RenderBox that why there is a mismatch type.

What excactly you are trying to share? so I can help with that

Edit:

You need to extract share button into its own widget. Try the following complete code. It works.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
  import 'package:share/share.dart';

  class Everything extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      // TODO: implement createState
      return _EverythingState();
    }
  }

  class _EverythingState extends State<Everything> {
    Widget _buildEventCards(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
      var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 14.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 0.0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                document['image'],
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Icon(document['icon']),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Wrap(
                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Chip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          label: Text(
                            document['date'],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Chip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          label: Text(document['source']),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Chip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          label: Text(
                            document['location'],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: width,
                      child: Text(
                        document['title'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(document['desc']),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'More',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 190, 208, 1.0)),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('webview clicked');
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => WebviewScaffold(
                                  url: document['url'],
                                  appBar: AppBar(
                                    title: Text(document['source']),
                                    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(
                                      135,
                                      142,
                                      136,
                                      1.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15.0,
                        ),
                        new MyButton(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stories').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  _buildEventCards(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            );
          });
    }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   // TODO: implement initState
  //   super.initState();

  //   FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
  //   var bannerAd = _buildBanner()..load();
  // }
  }

  class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyButton({
      Key key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          'Share',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 93, 62, 1.0)),
        ),
        color: Colors.grey[100],
        onPressed: () {
          final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
          Share.share('Hello this is a test',
              sharePositionOrigin:
              box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) &
              box.size);
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I’m trying to allow users to share stuff via Facebook and Twitter

Comment: what is this stuff ? what types ? where it come from in your widget tree

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it gave me another error. I added the trace back to my question

Comment: You need to stop the app and run it so it completely build

Comment: That worked thank you. Can you explain to me what you did?

Comment: context.findRenderObject() returns a RenderSliverList because your main object RenderObject is but actualy share method sharePositionOrigin: expect RenderBox object by extracting FlatButton into it is own widget it will return the correct type ... hope that help

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still having issues on this. Here is a code that works for me.

```
shareData(BuildContext context){
  Share.share('Some text here', 
    subject: 'Update the coordinate!',
    sharePositionOrigin: Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, width, height) 
  );
}
```