# Getting NoSuchmethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_HomeViewState.onTap'

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error on running my Flutter app (on device)

> NoSuchmethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function
> '_HomeViewState.onTap'  Reciever: Closure: (int) => dynamic from
> Function 'onTap':.  Tried calling: _HomeViewState.onTap() Found:
> _HomeViewState.onTap(int) => dynamic

Here is login_view_model.dart file which I think I am getting error in:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:student_community/core/services/authentication.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/home_view/home_view.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/login_view/login_view.dart';

class LoginViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int noOfUsers = 0;
  String userName, userImage;
  String get getUserName => userName;
  String get getUserImage => userImage;
  final AuthenticationService authenticationService = AuthenticationService();

  navigateToHomeView(BuildContext context) {
    logIn().whenComplete(() {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          PageTransition(
              child: HomeView(), type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop));
    });
  }

  Future logIn() async {
    try {
      await authenticationService.signInWithGoogle().then((user) {
        if (user.uid != null) {
          userName = user.displayName;
          userImage = user.photoURL;
          print(userName);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
        // Show Error Widget
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }

  Future logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await authenticationService.signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            PageTransition(
                child: LoginView(), type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
        // Show Error Widget
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I think the code above is not formatted correctly.
> Please forgive me because I am new to Stackoverflow.

> This is my 'home_view.dart' file:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:student_community/app/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:student_community/app/constants/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:student_community/core/viewmodels/login_view_model.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/blogs_view/blogs_view.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/home_view/home_view_widgets.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/podcasts_view/podcasts_view.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/views/video_view/video_view.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/widgets/app_bar.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  int index = 0;
  PageController pageController = PageController();
  onTap(int i) {
    setState(() {
      index = i;
    });
    pageController.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColorFaint,
      drawer: Drawer(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: appbar(titleText: 'Student Community', leadingWidget: null, actions: [
        IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.message)),
        IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
        hSizedBox1,
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false).logOut(context);
          },
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                    .getUserImage),
          ),
        )
      ]),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: (int pageIndex) {
          setState(() {
            index = pageIndex;
          });
        },
        children: [
          BlogsView(),
          VideoView(),
          PodcastsView(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomAppBar(index, onTap),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my 'home_view_widgets' where I have my 'bottomAppBar' Widget:

```
import 'package:custom_navigation_bar/custom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:student_community/app/constants/colors.dart';

Widget bottomAppBar(int index, Function onTap) {
  return CustomNavigationBar(
    
    strokeColor: yellowColor,
    scaleFactor: 0.2,
    scaleCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
    bubbleCurve: Curves.ease,
    currentIndex: index,
    onTap: onTap(),
    selectedColor: yellowColor,
    backgroundColor: darkColor,

    items: [

      CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.menuOutline)),
      CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.video)),
      CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.speaker)),

    ]);
}
```

Comment: please add your UI here.Think you call Issue in the onTap() method in the UI

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: add your ``bottomAppBar`` widget code

Comment: I have added my `bottomAppBar` widget code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of your `bottomAppBar` function to

```dart
Widget bottomAppBar(int index, dynamic Function(int) onTap) {
```

and remove the `onTap` call on the `CustomNavigationBar` parameter:

```dart
return CustomNavigationBar(
  // ...
  onTap: onTap(),
  // ...
);
```

Comment: I am getting this error ```1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.```                                                                                Getting Error at onTap Method

Comment: Please Help me!

Comment: @AnoopMasterCoder I've updated my code, see if there is any error now. If there's still, please post the full traceback.

Comment: How do I get the stack trace. I am a complete beginner. I know it's silly. Please help me.

Comment: @AnoopMasterCoder Take a look at the *The Error* section of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422293/9997212), it looks like that.

Comment: Thank you very very very much enzo it solved my problem.

Comment: Once again Thank You Very Much

Comment: But now there is a problem. I am getting many Exceptions every where. But they are not causing me any problem. Thank you very much Enzo.